# Hide webview when a url is called android studio

Tags: java, android, webview

I've a problem and i don't know how to solved it.

I made a little program with a switch button.
When the button is switched on then a url is been send and when switch is  off it sends another url.

The code works but when the link is sended it opens a webview.

```
public void onToggleClicked(View view) {
        // Is the toggle on?
        boolean on = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();

        if (on) {
            // Enable vibrate
            Intent myWebLink = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            myWebLink.setData(Uri.parse("https://xxxxxxx));

            startActivity(myWebLink);
            //WebView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        } else {
            // Disable vibrate
            Intent myWebLink = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            myWebLink.setData(Uri.parse("https://xxxxxx"));

            startActivity(myWebLink);
        }
    }
```

is it possible to make it so that i don't se the webview, so that my program always stays in front.

i tryed `WebView.setVisibility(View.GONE);` but by `setVisibilty` i get a error.

Please can somebody help me with this?

Comment: Why do you want to show a webview if it is to be hidden always?

Comment: I don't want to show it, because the link what is sended is for turning example a light on or off. the link is from triggi for a click on click off system. So there i don't want to see the webview. It's only for use at home.

Comment: what do you mean by send url ? you want to call any url ? because here you're passing just passing url in web view

Comment: i want to send the url but i don't want to see the webview or browser, just to send the command.

Answer (score 0):

You're starting a new activity, so this implies "opening the webview" (in this case, will be a browser). You could use a real `WebView`, but I suggest you to use Retrofit or some other library like it to make the HTTP requests without having to resort to a complex object like a `WebView`.

Comment: Do you have a example?

Comment: You just need to follow the project documentation https://square.github.io/retrofit/